# Missing Shared Visual Studio Project Template

Tags: visual-studio, xaf, desktop-bridge

I am following [Manuel Grundner's blog post on using the Desktop Bridge with XAF](http://blog.delegate.at)  which references [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/shared-projects?tabs=windows).

I need to add a shared project template.
The blog post shows it is in the Windows Classic Desktop section

[image: Shared Project Template]

However the template is missing in my VS 2017 15.9.3.

[Update]

I wondered if I could use the Share Extension(iOS) project in iOS Extensions. However when I tried It was not visible as a shared project inside the reference manager.

[Update]

I have been able to work around the problem by using the shared project from the Github repository associated with the post.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/184544/shared-projects-missing.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53770437/entityframework-sqlserver-missing-in-release-mode